# runtime.duffcopy is called a lot

Tags: go

When profiling my app, and run top, I see

```
Showing top 10 nodes out of 31 (cum >= 0.12s)
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
    13.93s 63.00% 63.00%     13.93s 63.00%  runtime.duffcopy
```

I am struggling to know when and why it is called and if there is something I can do to improve this? Would you need to see the function from where these calls are made from or is there any general rule-of-thumb that I should think about?

I have read that named return values can improve this, but its quite a big function testing a lot of conditions (returning true or false), so don't know if its a good idea to implement that.

Thanks

Comment: You must provide **much** more information. Your question is unanswerable. Look at the functions calling duffcopy and get rid of copying values is the best advice possible without more information.

Answer (score 12):

Think I just solved it. I had a look at the assembly output and saw that I had a

```
for _, v := range c.Items
```

an Item is a relatively big object, so I replaced above loop with

```
for index := 0; index < len(c.Items); index++
```

and used direct access of the objects like c.Items[index]. Top now shows:

```
350ms  4.85% 60.47%      350ms  4.85%  runtime.duffcopy
```

The overall execution time was cut from 12s to 4s. Quite nice :)

Comment: can anyone explain to me why this makes it so much faster?

Comment: Without the full code it is impossible to say for sure, but my guess is that the loop only accessed a small amount of data in each Item. Using the `for _, v := range c.Items` tells the compiler to copy the full item for each loop iteration, which would be a large waste of time if only a small percentage of the item is actually used. Using explicit indexes to access the fields would avoid the unnecessary copies.